# Task not serializable exception in dataframe map function

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I need to convert the datatypes of columns in dataframe and catch all data type conversion failures. I have tried the below option but it throws "Task not serializable".

```
    var errorListBuffer = new ListBuffer[Map[String, String]]()
    df.map(r => {
      val value = r.getAs(columnName).toString
      val index = r.fieldIndex(columnName)
      Try {
        val cleanValue = value match {
          case n if r.isNullAt(index) => null
          case x => x.trim
        }
     new_type match {
       case "date" => new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat).parse(cleanValue))
       case "datetime" => new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").format(new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat).parse(cleanValue))
       case "string" => toLower match {
         case "1" => cleanValue.toLowerCase
         case _ => cleanValue
         }
       case _ => cleanValue
       }
     } match {
     case Success(v) => org.apache.spark.sql.Row.fromSeq(r.toSeq ++ v)
     case Failure(e) => errorListBuffer += Map(
      LOADER_COLUMN_NAME -> columnName,
      LOADER_LEVEL -> "ERROR",
      LOADER_ERROR_MESSAGE -> e.getMessage,
      LOADER_RECORD_UUID -> r.getAs(LOADER_UUID).toString)
    org.apache.spark.sql.Row.fromSeq(r.toSeq ++ null)
   }
 })
  var dfnew = sqlContext.createDataFrame(df, schema)
```

Please let me know how I can resolve this.

Comment: I am pretty sure that using `errorListBuffer` this way isn't going to do what you want it to. When the map func gets passed down to the executors, it will make a copy of `errorListBuffer`, which the executor will append to (if it hits an error). When the map finishes, and control returns to the driver app, their copies of `errorListBuffer` (with any errors collected) will be lost.

Comment: Oh I see. What would be a better way of doing this? I also tried using a udf that returns a map of converted values & errors. Though this approach works, its painfully slow.